# When to use super.render(); super.dispose();super.pause(); and super.resize(w,h); in Libgdx?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, libgdx, super

In the following code, I extend `MyGame` from `Game`. I have two questions:

1. Do we need to call `super` method for all `render()`, `dispose()`, `pause()` and `resize(w,h)`?
   Many people haven't put `super.pause()` and `super.resize(w,h)` in the code.
   So, I am very confused about the super calls here.
2. I try to remove all the above super methods (`super.render()`; also removed), I can still run my code successfully under desktop mode (i.e. desktopLauncher.java). Can someone explain why?

Here is my code:

```
public class MyGame extends Game {
    Game game;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        game = this;
        setScreen(new MainMenu(game));
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        super.render();
    }
    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
    }
    @Override
    public void pause() {
        super.pause();
    }
    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
         super.resize(width, height);  

    }
}
```

If I delete all unused methods and just keep create() method as follows, I will run the code sucessfully.

```
    public class MyGame extends Game {
    Game game;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        game = this;
        setScreen(new MainMenu(game));
    }
    }
```

Anyone wants to explain this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `super` methods invoke the same method on the super class (in this case [Game](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/Game.java)).  If you [check the source](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/Game.java), you can see those methods on Game just forward the call to the containing `screen` instance (if any).  For example, in your `render` method if you invoke `super.render()` that will execute the `Game.render` method.

So, for your specific case, the methods may or may not be strictly necessary (mostly depending on if you have a `screen` set and if your screen implementation itself needs the callbacks).  But, in general, when extending implementations of a class's methods, you generally want to invoke the super class method so that whatever it needs to get done, will get done.

Many of the Libgdx and Android classes are designed this way (they implement a bit of functionality but expect subclasses to implement more, and the subclass is expected to invoke the superclass method).  Ideally the documentation on the class would explain one way or the other, but I think you should assume (especially in this case) that invoking the superclass method is the right thing to do.

Comment: I discover the following: if render() is empty, I got a black screen. It is clear because I haven't used super.render(). However, I can simply not to override the render() method. Just override create(), I can run the code sucessfully.